# Gulp - Excluding Paths dont work for me

Tags: javascript, gulp

I saw a lot of google entries about the question "How to Exclude in Gulp Paths" but none of those work for me.

the only thing that works was this:

```
gulp.task('sassPlatform', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        './src/sass/platforms/**',
        // TODO find a way to make this shorter
        '!./src/sass/platforms/globals/*.scss',
        '!./src/sass/platforms/globals/'
    ])
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/platforms'));
});
```

The point is that I got this folder structure:

```
scss
  |_platforms
    |_globals
      |_content.scss
      |_footer.scss
      |_globals.scss
      |_header.scss
    |_superfolder1
      |_main.scss
    |_superfolder2
      |_main.scss
    |_superfolder3
      |_main.scss
    |_and alot of superfolders more...
```

I want to keep folder structure and take all the fields in the superfolders. BUT NOT THE GLOBAL FOLDER.

With my code this works correctly. But I want to understand why it doesn't work with:

```
'!./src/sass/platforms/globals{/, *, *.scss}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Glup uses internally [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) which expandas all section in curly brackets before matching any patterns so writting:

```
'!./src/sass/platforms/globals{/, *, *.scss}'
```

gets expanded into:

```
'!./src/sass/platforms/globals/'
'!./src/sass/platforms/globals*'
'!./src/sass/platforms/globals*.scss'
```

and this is probably not what you want. Try using this instead:

```
'!./src/sass/platforms/globals/{*, *.scss}'
```